# UIPageViewController in ContainerView Not Swiping (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I can make this work on full viewcontroller, but in a container view I can only load the first image from an array of images but it won't recognize a swipe. Do I need to reference the container view or something? Here is what I am doing

I am loading images from Assets and looking to paginate based on NSArray()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayImages = ["one.png", "two.png", "three.png"]
}
```

I have VC1, with a container view.

The container view has a segue to VC2 which is UIPageViewController

VC2 has a segue to VC3, which has a UIImageView.

- How can I cycle through array of Images or do I need a seperate VC for each 'page'?

Cheers